# How to fix smilies in Gmail showing as "J"

Tags: gmail

Is there a way to fix smilies in received emails that looks like "J" in Gmail?

Other mail clients (such as Outlook) changes ":)" to smile character in Wingdings font that is letter "J". Although, in HTML style attribute `font-family: Wingdings;` is set, it still shows as "J" in Firefox.

The solution could be adding encoding support for Wingdings font, but I would be more interested in Gmail [Apps Script](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/) (via [Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/07/gmail-snooze-with-apps-script.html)) solution, so it would work on other computers for my account.

Comment: Which version of Firefox?

Comment: It also shows as `J` in the latest version of Chrome, and in Opera 11.51

Comment: Currently I'm using Firefox 7.0.1. However, as Wingdings is an obscure proprietary font, I don't think other versions have support for it.

Comment: @Domas You can get rid of this problem if u were using Firefox 3, a little edit in a font property file would have solved this problem.

Comment: Gmail running into iPhone Mail through Exchange renders the `J`, as well, I believe.

Answer (score 6):

A receiver-side solution to this problem would be to install the [SWEC (Symbola-based Wingdings Emoticons Compatibility) font](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwDrnPQfa-aMOEx0bEZCQUNrSGs).

It provides basic compatibility with Wingdings emoticons. (In Wingdings, "J" represents a smile, "K" represents a lack of expression, and "L" represents a frown.) Background: certain versions of Microsoft e-mail clients still in use change user-typed expressions such as ":)", ":|", and ":(" into "J", "K", and "L", respectively, and then specify Wingdings as the font family; recipients on systems which do not include a Wingdings-compatible font are not able to see the intended emoticons, which can cause confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there's always installing Wingdings, but doesn't Gmail have its own set of emoticons? This would be rendered as a tiny image, rather than a font glyph, and therefore independent of any fonts you may not have installed.

Comment: Gmail has its own Emoticons, yes. However, as I've stated in my questions, the problem is when other mail clients sends messages (received in gmail) where smileys/emoticons are used from Wingdings font.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Sorry!